# swapping adjacent corners on a 3x3 cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, mechanical-puzzles

My son received a 3x3 cube for Christmas which has oddly shaped pieces. I have solved as for a Rubik's cube but have ended up with 2 corners I can't solve on the top layer. They are 2 adjacent corners. I need to switch the red and the blue corners in the picture. The other two corners are in the correct locations though not correctly orientated yet.

I don't have the original box or pictures of the original cube so is it possible I have the faces mixed up?
I would have thought the centre of the faces stay opposite as on a Rubik's cube?

[image: image of unsolved corners]

Comment: NOW SOLVED!! After posting this I tried googling various versions of cube and it seems I was solving this incorrectly - the small squares on the sides line up vertically. I was actually making it more complicated than it is!

Comment: Is it called a "Windmill Cube"? Knowing the name of the puzzle helps a lot!

Answer (score 5):

As you probably already know, on a normal Rubik's cube it is impossible to swap two (corner) pieces while keeping the other pieces in their places, unless you take the cube apart.

However, in this case you have a middle layer that has a different solved configuration. If you change that middle layer so that all its centre pieces are rotated 180 degrees, and the four edges are all flipped and shifted over one spot, then it will again be solved. Even better, its cuts will line up exactly with the solved bottom layer.

Once you solve the middle layer that way, the last layer will become solvable.